# Proof of subset of the image of a set family

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I believe I have done the proof correctly, may I have a proof verification? If anything is wrong please let me know.

Problem

Prove

if $f:A \rightarrow B$ with domain $A$ and $S_i$ with $i \in I$ is a family of sets were $\forall i \in I$,$S_i \subseteq A$, then

$f(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} S_{i}) \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} f(S_{i})$

Assume $b \in f(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} S_{i})=\{y \in B:\exists x \in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} S_{i} s.t. f(x)=b\}$.

Then $\exists x\in \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} S_{i}$ such that $f(x)=b$

$\implies x \in S_i, \forall i \in I$

$\implies b=f(x) \in f(S_i), \forall i \in I$

Thus

$f(\bigcap\limits_{i \in I} S_{i}) \subseteq \bigcap\limits_{i \in I} f(S_{i})$

Comment: Yes your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Just a remark.

we don't write

$$x\in S_i, \forall i\in I$$

you should replace by

$$(\forall i\in I) \;\; x\in S_i$$

Or

$$x\in S_i , \text{ for all } i\in I$$

Comment: I realize this relation is an equality if the function is injective, how would I prove the other subset direction?